# how to check all object in NSMutableArray same value

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have on `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0", nil];
```

now  I want check if all object in my array are to same and equal to 0 doing certain work!!!. but I don't know about this.
please guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My friend try this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0", nil];
NSCountedSet *filter = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:array];

//this condition check number of 0 value with your array count
//if number of 0 equal to array count this means that all object in array is 0
if ([filter countForObject:@"0"] == [array count]) {
   NSLog(@"all objects are 0");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the usual for statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
    NSString *string = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    // Check for >0
}
```

Or [fast enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html):

```
for (NSString *string in array)
{
    // Check for >0
}
```

I didn't fill on purpose the check part, considering that you are a iOS (i guess) beginner can i recommend a good book on iOS programming? [iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/ios-programming/)

Comment: my friend I want check if all object in my array are to same and equal to 0 doing certain work!!!